# Select from where as

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

Using oracle, how can I do this using a single query?

```
VALUE       TYPE        IDentifier     
12           aa         123
123          bb         123
323          aa         1234
1212         cc         123
2            aa         12345
123          dd         123

SELECT IDentifier , SUM(VALUE) AS typeAASum WHERE TYPE = 'aa'
SELECT IDentifier , SUM(VALUE) AS typeBBSum WHERE TYPE = 'bb'
SELECT IDentifier , SUM(VALUE) AS typeCCSum WHERE TYPE = 'cc'
```

So my results will be, again in a single query,

```
   IDentifier     TypeAASum    TypeBBSum     TypeCCSum
```

It's important that I only get one row per Identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Identifier,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'aa' THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS typeAASum,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'bb' THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS typeBBSum,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'cc' THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS typeCCSum
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Identifier
```

Comment: Is it really that simple...?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg Yes, that's why he used that as an answer

Comment: Worked perfect. The Value was a calculated field and still performed extremely well.

Comment: So just to get a better oracle grasp, does the CASE statements cause the query to check every row 3 times in this?